# Не могу передать аргументы в KerasClassifier

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, keras

Подскажите, как в `KerasClassifier` передать в `build_fn` функцию, которая зависит от параметров. `model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model(a, b))`. Но, в  силу того, что `build_fn callback`, передать аргументы нельзя. А как можно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим, что вы объявили функцию:

```
def create_model(max_features, max_len):
    ...
```

тогда следующая конструкция должна работать (обратите внимание на использование **именованных** параметров):

```
model = KerasClassifier(
                build_fn=create_model,
                max_features=max_features_variable,
                max_len=max_len_variable,
                epochs=150
                )
```

[Из доки](https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/):

> `sk_params` takes both model parameters and fitting parameters. Legal
>   model parameters are the **arguments of  `build_fn`**

Comment: Окей, спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 2):

Возможное решение -- это использование partial

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial

```
model = KerasClassifier(
                build_fn=functools.partial(create_model, max_features, max_len),
                epochs=150
                )
```